# How to redirect everything but an specific path on a htaccess file?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create an `htaccess` file so that everything gets redirected to the root of the site except for an specific path `/api/date`.

I have this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've made some research on javascript regex and it seems that it is not possible to exclude words. So it is possible to do this here? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with below we are excluding `/api/date` and passing everything apart from that.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!(\/api\/date)$).+$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```